# How can I run a javascript function when input changes

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When a user creates a new account on my website I want to check if the name already exists. I want this check to run when they leave the username input box and go to enter a password.

I tried :

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="check_user(this.value)"/>
```

Comment: no this is for register that if this user exist cannot submit whit this username.

Comment: What you are looking for is the `blur` event. But @Awais provided an even better solution, as the `change` event will be raised, when the input looses focus, but only if the text changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect changed input text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153047/detect-changed-input-text-box)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the "onblur" event. It fires when a control loses its focus, which seems to be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 25):

Call the function on the `change` event of text field:

```
<input name="username" onChange="check_user(this.value);" type="text"/>
```

Comment: i did this but when switch between inputs by clicking on others or tab for switch function didnt respond!

Comment: are you calling function with correct spellings on all inputs>

Comment: +1, `change` is better than `blur` and the `input` needs indeed a `name`.

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling agree with u

Comment: @mamrezo: Double check your code, it should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/VNV5P/1/

Answer (score 13):

Because you used `onkeyup` in your code example, it sounds like you are looking to call a function on every keystroke. If that is the case, then instead of `onchange` - which fires when the `input` loses focus - you should use `oninput` which will fire anytime there is a change inside of input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for check the duplication of user.
you have to write server side code for that.

Comment: i know this is an ajax work but instead of onkeyup what should i type?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire when something specific is type into the window:

```
phr = 'lol'
ltr = phr.split('')
text = ''

document.addEventListener('keyup',function(k){
    if (ltr.includes(k.key)) {
        text += k.key
        if (text == phr) {
            console.log('Typed!')
            text = ''
        }
    } else {
        text = ''
    }})
```

As a function your can use it like:

```
function wtt(phrase,clb) {
    phr = phrase
    ltr = phr.split('')
    text = ''

    document.addEventListener('keyup',function(k){
        if (ltr.includes(k.key)) {
            text += k.key
            if (text == phr) {
                clb()
                text = ''
            }
        } else {
            text = ''
        }})
}

wtt('my phrase', function () {
    console.log('dostuff')
})
```