# Detect changed input text box

Tags: jquery, input

I've looked at numerous other questions and found very simple answers, including the code below.  I simply want to detect when someone changes the content of a text box but for some reason it's not working...  I get no console errors.  When I set a breakpoint in the browser at the `change()` function it never hits it.

```js
$('#inputDatabaseName').change(function () { 
    alert('test'); 
});
```

```html
<input id="inputDatabaseName">
```

Comment: just a couple of things to try:  give the input a type="text" and make it a singleton element.  <input id="inputDatabaseName" type="text"/>

Answer (score 608, accepted):

You can use the [`input` Javascript event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input) in jQuery like this:

```
$('#inputDatabaseName').on('input',function(e){
    alert('Changed!')
});
```

In pure JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change",function () {
  alert("Input Changed");
})
```

Or like this:

```
<input id="inputDatabaseName" onchange="youFunction();"
onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();"/>
```

Comment: Can't seem to find documentation for this event, but it works exactly the way I expect it to. Any idea where I can find the doc page?

Comment: You can find it on the list of HTML5 events : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp or here http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php

Comment: This solution is actually far better than using keyup. E.g. IE lets the user clear input field by clicking an X which does not trigger keyup.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the input is changed with JavaScript.

Comment: Closest solution so far, but still doesn't work when browser performs autofill on the textboxes.

Comment: Since the point is to identify when the content of the input has *changed*, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is far better than the first answer. Ctrl, Shift keys all count as keyup. And the worst part is, if you type fast, several input would register as only one keyup event.

Comment: why jQuery does not have an `input(handler)` method?, how to know all the events which I can use apart from http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: You can use [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and here is all the **HTML events** that you can use http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: this does not work if input value changed by code `$('#inputDatabaseName').val("hello world!")`

Comment: I was using "keyup" instead of "input" and the function it was calling was running twice. Changing to "input" fixed it.

Answer (score 185):

try keyup instead of change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#inputDatabaseName').keyup(function () { alert('test'); });
   });
</script>
```

Here's [the official jQuery documentation for .keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

Comment: *sigh* I swear I tried that (after looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443292/how-to-implement-onchange-of-input-type-text-with-jquery)... but apparently not because it works now!

Comment: change only fires when the element looses focus and keyup is fired when a key on the keyboard is released.

Comment: what if the user pastes code using ctrl+v or by dragging a selected text with the mouse onto the #inputDatabaseName? How do you detect that?

Comment: The main problem with this is it still does not take into account if the content actually changes. Only that a button was pressed

Comment: @Metropolis, you've seen my answer??  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23266812/3160597

Answer (score 121):

Each answer is missing some points, so here is my solution:

```js
$("#input").on("input", function(e) {
  var input = $(this);
  var val = input.val();

  if (input.data("lastval") != val) {
    input.data("lastval", val);

    //your change action goes here 
    console.log(val);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<p>Try to drag the letters and copy paste</p>
```

The `Input Event` fires on **Keyboard** input, **Mouse Drag**, **Autofill** and **Copy-Paste** tested on Chrome and Firefox.
Checking for previous value makes it detect real changes, which means not firing when pasting the same thing or typing the same character or etc.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/g6pcp/473/

---

**update:**

And if you like to run your `change function` **only when user finishes typing** and prevent firing the change action several times, you could try this:

```js
var timerid;
$("#input").on("input", function(e) {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if ($(this).data("lastval") != value) {

    $(this).data("lastval", value);
    clearTimeout(timerid);

    timerid = setTimeout(function() {
      //your change action goes here 
      console.log(value);
    }, 500);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

If user starts typing (e.g. "foobar") this code prevents your `change action` to run for every letter user types and and only runs when user stops typing, This is good specially for when you send the input to the server (e.g. search inputs), that way server does **only one** search for `foobar` and not six searches for `f` and then `fo` and then `foo` and `foob` and so on.

Comment: This was the first to work from about 6 I tried. Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Almost works on IE9: if you delete a character, it doesn't fire the event. Very good workaround though

Comment: @Soma, as others say "breaking IE is not a flaw it's a feature" ;)
although IE is not continued anymore but if you have a fix for that let us know

Comment: I know, but I had to do it for work :( As a matter of fact, I do : use `$("#input").focusout(function () {})`. When you click outside your input, the event is fired. Works on current version of Chrome and Firefox, and IE9

Comment: @Soma, if that's the only way for IE to work you could use it my way with only changing this line `$("#input").on("input focusout",function(e){`

Comment: what the 'e' argument ?

Comment: @Ehsan, `e` stands for `event` which is the event object that jQuery passes to the callback functions. It is merely there out of habit and hasn't been used. You could remove it if you don't need it

Answer (score 24):

Text inputs do not fire the `change` event until they lose focus. Click outside of the input and the alert will show.

If the callback should fire before the text input loses focus, use the [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup) event.

Comment: `change` is working here : http://jsfiddle.net/g6pcp/  ; `keyup` alert after each key which is not a good way

Comment: @diEcho I think the alert is just an example to get his code working...not what he intends to do in the end.

Comment: @diEcho What Scott said, it was just for testing purposes.  That's how I debug :D

Comment: @Scott please please please use a proper debugger rather than `alert()`. It will make debugging **so much easier.**

Answer (score 14):

`onkeyup, onpaste, onchange, oninput` seems to be failing when the browser performs autofill on the textboxes. To handle such a case include "`autocomplete='off'`" in your textfield to prevent browser from autofilling the textbox,

Eg,

```
<input id="inputDatabaseName" autocomplete='off' onchange="check();"
 onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();" />

<script>
     function check(){
          alert("Input box changed");
          // Things to do when the textbox changes
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had a textbox that was attached to a datepicker. The only solution that worked for me was to handle it inside the onSelect event of the datepicker.

```
<input type="text"  id="bookdate">

$("#bookdate").datepicker({            
     onSelect: function (selected) {
         //handle change event here
     }
});
```

Comment: Using the same datepicker and needed the same thing, thanks! But it's still weird that input change cannot be detected as a change on <select> can be detected.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, **it always works**.

```
$(function() {
    $("#my_input").on("change paste keyup", function() {
       alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `keydown` too:

```
$('#fieldID').on('keydown', function (e) {
  //console.log(e.which);
  if (e.which === 8) {
    //do something when pressing delete
    return true;
  } else {
    //do something else
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inputDatabaseName').change(function(){
    alert('Changed!')
});
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp)

Answer (score 0):

$(document).on('input', '#inputDatabaseName', function () { alert("yess"); });

Comment: Please leave some explanation. Also you code block when you include code snippet.

Answer (score -4):

WORKING:

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNombre").keyup(function () {
    var txt = $(this).val();
        $('.column').each(function () {
            $(this).show();
            if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) == -1) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    //}
});
```

Comment: That looks like code for a different question... what is that stuff about uppercasing values and showing / hiding content about?

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know why but you make me laugh so much. This answer and your comment made my day.