# Input is not detecting that it is empty if removing text with "ctrl + a + backspace"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing some easy `div` filtering with jQuery and input field. It is working, however it is not detecting that it is empty if I remove input using " <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> ", in other words if I select all text and remove it. What causes this?

It is not reordering divs back to default if using the keyboard commands but is going back to normal if you <kbd>backspace</kbd> every character.

This is how I do it:

```
$('#brandSearch').keyup(function() {
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (valThis.length == 0) {
        $('.card').show();
    } else {
        $('.card').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).parent().show(): $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: *"if I remove input using "ctrl + a""* `CTRL+A` doesn't remove input.

Comment: and press backspace. Sorry!

Comment: Not that it should matter in this case... but why not use the `input` event rather than `keyup`, I wonder?

Comment: Try registering the `.on('input', ..` event.  See this example here :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15706843/3504007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` block that handles the empty string is not showing the same elements that the `else` block hides. The `else` block calls `.parent()` but the `if` block does not.

So the `else` case shows or hides the *parent* of each `.card` element, but the `if` case shows the `.card` elements themselves—*without unhiding their parents*. See my comments added to the code (I also reformatted the conditional expression in the `else` for clarity):

```
$('#brandSearch').keyup(function() {
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (valThis.length == 0) {
        // Show all of the .card elements
        $('.card').show();
    } else {
        $('.card').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            // Show or hide the *parent* of this .card element
            text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0 ?
                $(this).parent().show() :
                $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    };
});
```

Since it sounds like the non-empty-string case is working correctly, it should just be a matter of adding `.parent()` in the `if` block so it matches the others:

```
$('#brandSearch').keyup(function() {
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (valThis.length == 0) {
        // Show the parent of each .card element
        $('.card').parent().show();
    } else {
        // Show or hide the parent of each .card element
        $('.card').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0 ?
                $(this).parent().show() :
                $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    };
});
```

This is the kind of situation where familiarity with your browser's debugging tools would pay off big time. The `.show()` or `.hide()` methods manipulate the DOM, and by using the DOM inspector you could easily see which elements are being hidden and shown.

In fact, as a learning exercise I recommend un-fixing the bug temporarily by going back to your original code, and then open the DOM inspector and see how it reveals the problem. While you're there, also try out the JavaScript debugger and other tools.

If you use Chrome, here's an [introduction to the Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Other browsers have similar tools and documentation for them.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I actually didn't saw your comment before. But what is the difference between `.length == 0` and `val == " "`?

Comment: I don't see `val == " "` in the code, but that would test whether `val` is a string consisting of a single space character. If you're asking about `val == ""`, that would be essentially the same thing as `val.length == 0`, assuming `val` is a string.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clearing this up, I just started the Jquery and javascript language and there are so many ways declare things.

Comment: Well you're off to a great start! :-) See the note I added to the answer about the browser's debugging tools. They will really help you track down problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working just fine:

```js
$('#brandSearch').keyup(function() {
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (valThis.length == 0) {
        $('.card').show();
      console.log("input is empty");
    } else {
      console.log("input is not empty");                  
        $('.card').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).parent().show(): $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="brandSearch">
```

Comment: Weird, it is really working. Is it possible that it is because I use materializecss input field? I see that console shows input is not empty but it doesn't go back. It doesn't show all divs again.

Comment: I am not familiar with that type of input, but it is certainly possible that it only triggers the even when a printable character is pressed.

Comment: Also, `.keyup` isn't the best event to register against if you wish to detect change in a timely manner.